# Reviews not same format as Articles in achemso

Tags: bibtex

I'm submitting to ACS Nano using the `achemso` class. I use an external `.bib` file.
Is it normal that the bibitems that are treated as `@Review` are not formatted the same as `@Article`? For the latter, it includes the journal name, while for the Review, it omits the journal and it puts the title italic instead...

> 1. Geim, A. K.; Novoselov, K. S. The rise of graphene. *Nature Materials* 2007, *6*, 183–191.
> 2. Neto, A. H. C.; Guinea, F.; Peres, N. M. R.; Novoselov, K. S.; Geim, A. K. *The electronic properties of graphene*, 2009.

With the second being the review...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Tame the BeaST](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf), pp. 14--15, `@review` is not a standard BibTeX type. Also, `achemso.bst` does not make provisions for such a type. My guess is that your `@review` bibitem is treated (and formatted) as `@misc`.

Comment: Spot on. An article which is a review is still classed as `@article` (not just for `achemso`: this is general).

Comment: +1 for the link. That looks pretty good. Although, pros use biblatex, so parts of it are irrelevant...

Comment: @Seamus @Joseph @Lockstep : Thanks for your answers. `@Review` comes from the fact I'm using Mekentosj Papers software which exports using this format for reviews... I'll change them manually into `@Article` then.